# Why does the function not execute a specific line

Tags: c, string, recursion

I am trying to build a function that takes a positive integer number and represents it in a string
using recursion. The string isn't initialized.

```
void intToStr(int num, char s[]){

    if (num / 10 == 0) {
        s[0] = num + '0';
        s[1] = '\0';
    }
    else {
        intToStr(num / 10, s);
        s[strlen(s)] = num % 10 + '0';
        s[strlen(s) + 1] = '\0';
    }
}
```

But I don't understand why when I run the code it skips this line

`s[strlen(s) + 1] = '\0';`

Comment: What exactly are you doing to decide it skips that line? Are you stepping through the code in a debugger, or looking at the result, or what?

Comment: I am going each line in debugger and I can see in the value of s that it didn't "close" the string. @Useless

Comment: If you're stepping each line in the debugger, you can see whether control transfers to that line or not. Does it? This is separate from _whether it had the expected effect_. What exactly were the contents of `s` and the value returned by `strlen` when you observed it doing the wrong thing?

Comment: Oh I understand now what you mean. it didn't skip the line but executed it with a faulty logic. after the line s[strlen(s)] =` num % 10 + '0'; ` strlen size is connected to the next '\0' in memory and the line after inserted '\0' after that one so it didn't change the length. Thanks for the help!

Comment: calling `strlen(s)`  repeatedly like that is a bad idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In:

```
        s[strlen(s)] = num % 10 + '0';
        s[strlen(s) + 1] = '\0';
```

`strlen` does not stay the same when the first line is executed. That first line puts a new character over the null that is terminating the string. Then the `strlen(s)` in the second line recalculates the string length. Since the null character is gone, `strlen` continues looking for a null character. What length it returns depends on whether there is another null character in the buffer already. If you did not initialize it, `strlen` could return some longer length, or the program could crash or otherwise misbehave.

You could solve this with:

```
        size_t length = strlen(s);
        s[length] = num % 10 + '0';
        s[length + 1] = '\0';
```

It might also be convenient to have `intToStr` return the length so it does not have to be recalculated each time:

```
size_t intToStr(int num, char s[])
{
    if (num / 10 == 0)
    {
        s[0] = num + '0';
        s[1] = '\0';
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        size_t length = intToStr(num / 10, s);
        s[length] = num % 10 + '0';
        s[length+1] = '\0';
        return length+1;
    }
}
```